# What is the cause of discrepancies among different word counters

Tags: ruby, word-count

I created a word counter in Ruby as a little exercise in learning Ruby.

I've used the word counters on JavaScriptKit.com and WordCountTool.com as well as the one in Open Office Writer.

Some text produced the following results

```
OpenOffice: 458 words
JavaScriptKit: 453 words
WordCountTool: 455 words
Mine: 461 words
```

My question is this: Why do the counts differ for the same exact excerpt across all counters?

What are problems in a script that might cause an inaccurate, but still close count?

What are some ways I could improve upon my script so that it's more accurate?

Comment: Could you post an example text that gives different counts? I'm guessing this could come from small differences such as whether hyphenated words are counted as one or two, and how it handles certain abbreviations s.a. this one.

Comment: I think its basically due to small inaccuracies like - Some programs would count a new word when they see a space, but this is incorrect, as they would see something like "and then...i realized" and see "then...i" as one word, or count hyphenated-words as one word.

Comment: Also character set issues may cause differences if some of the programs don't handle those properly. What character set is your text?

Comment: @serabe, it's not a question about specific code.. but really what causes differences in counts across scripts -- what would account for these differences, how to avoid being "wrong", etc.

Comment: @Melanie, sorry I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're really asking for a definition of a "word", which for counting purposes could mean very different things. Let's take your original post as an example.

The most simplistic counting tool would be

```
text.split.count                      #=> 111
```

Yet what if you had put `"Why do the counts differ/change for the same[...]"`? Well, clearly "differ/change" is two words, so we should probably count forward slashes as word delimiters. In fact, just because I forgot to put a space between a full stop and the next word, doesn't make them the same word, so let's include full stops as delimiters too. Yet I can't be bothered to check whether it's a URL, so those websites you mention will have to count as two words:

```
text.split(/[\s\.\/\?]+/).count       #=> 113
```

Ok, that's cool, but actually numbers are not technically words - and if they were spoken, 458 would be "four hundred and fifty eight" which is actually 5 words. So let's discount them too

```
text.split(/[\s\.\/\?0-9]+/).count    #=> 109
```

You get the idea. The results you got only differed by 8 words - so clearly their definitions of a word are not all that different. But word counts are only ever a rough guide, so don't worry about the discrepancies.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get different results depending on what the author of the WC has decided to be a 'word'. Certain types of punctuation could be classed as a word seperator depending on the counter as a well as whitespaces, newlines etc...

Some info from the wikipedia article on WC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_count

> Different word counting programs may give varying results, depending
>   on the definition of "word"